# maven: Specify submodules

Tags: maven, module, arguments

Is there a way to specify submodules to build, at the command line?

For example, I have a project:

```
<modules>
 <module>A</module>
 <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

and I would like to decide, at runtime in a shell script, wether i want to build A, B, or A and B.

I'd like to issue:

```
mvn -Dmodules=A,B
```

Is there an equivalent command which is possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's the `-pl` argument:

```
mvn -pl A,B
```

> *-pl,--projects*  - Comma-delimited list of specified reactor projects to build instead of all projects. A project can be specified by [groupId]:artifactId or by its relative path.